# Dockerize a .NET Application using SAP HANA connection

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hana

I have a problem and I don't know if is available to do it actually.

I'm trying to create a .NET application and connect it with SAP HANA Live database in my company.

I followed the tutorial [Connect Using the SAP HANA .NET Interface | Tutorials for SAP Developers](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-dot-net-core.html) and the connection works fine.

The problem comes when I want to deploy the application using docker instead IIS.

After publishing docker image HANA connection does not work, there is no exception or anything execution just stops at this:

```
HanaConnection conn = new(connectionString);
```

and hangs there, no errors, no messages, nothing.

What can it be? how can I even try to investigate it further?